# Renewing Production Push SSL Certificate - Apple APNS

Tags: certificate, apple-push-notifications, ssl-certificate

Our production push ssl certificate is going to expire soon.  If I generate a new certificate, will the other certificate remain valid until it is set to expire (at which point it must be replaced with the new certificate)?

Will both certificates work at the same time?

Just concerned about the timing.  For our app, we host a push server and so do a few of our customers.  I want to make sure creating a new certificate and updating our push server with the new certificate doesn't mess up our customers' push servers that will, for a time, still have the old certificate installed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems like you don't invalidate the old certificate...

> "You can generate a new certificate without revoking the old one, and
>   use them simultaneously to ensure they are working before revoking the
>   old one."

[At least according to this post](http://blog.boxedice.com/2010/06/05/how-to-renew-your-apple-push-notification-push-ssl-certificate/)

Comment: Thanks.  Thought this was the case, but good to have some assurance.

Comment: Ok you have both certificates enable, but in my server should i handle both too? I mean, when I establish a connection with apple servers I can use only one pem.

Comment: You only need the new certificates.