# Is revoke and recreate expired distribution certificate will break push notification of apps?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, certificate, apple-push-notifications

My distribution certificate of my deveveloper account is expired.

I want to revoke and recreate the certificate.

Will it break push notification of apps?

Thanks

Important: The certificate that I'm revoke/recreate is the account certificate, not push certificate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265815/renewing-production-push-ssl-certificate-apple-apns this will help you

Comment: If you revoke the certificates, then you have to create new push certificates and upload it to the server

Comment: @Ganee Do you mean revoke the account certificate?

Comment: Yes, even if you revoke the account certificates, you have to create new push certificates.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `CSR` of old one? Then recreate and set as did before Because By re-using the `CSR` you can keep using your existing private key and only the .cer file will change. 
Otherwise you need to create new one and also you get  a new private key.

Comment: The certificate that I'm revoke/recreate is the account certificate, not push certificate. Is you answer still valid?